# How to generate number pattern inside loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have the following code:

```js
for ( let i = 1; i <= 12; i++ ) {
    console.log(i % 4);
}
```

It generates the output:

```
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
0
```

I'm trying to change the pattern (`i % 4`) so it gives me the following sequence instead:

```
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
```

I don't want to use a variable for it, just change the pattern inside the `console.log` to a good one that doesn't rely on for example multiple tenary operators.

It should keep increasing 1 every 4 iterations and work for more than 12 iterations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could divide the value by `4` and take the value with [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) for the next integer number.

```js
for ( let i = 1; i <= 12; i++ ) {
    console.log(Math.ceil(i / 4));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I could not remember at all what was it to make such sequence and was complicated to search it aswell.